# jQuery sortable - how to add a sort indicator?

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable, indicator

I've successfully implemented the jQuery sortable() plugin but want to enhance it with a
sort indicator. This would be a vertical bar in between the items where the draggable can be dropped. See the image below for an example. Can this easily be achieved with the sortable() plugin?

[alt text http://www.host2000.be/_temp/sortable.jpg](http://www.host2000.be/_temp/sortable.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [drop placeholder](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder) with a style that only shows the border on one side.